# How can I bulk remove small images from Google Photos?

Tags: google-plus-photos

I recently uploaded a bunch of photos to Google Photos, and accidentally included a load of smaller thumbnails in the upload:

[image]

Is there an easy way to remove these in bulk from Google Photos? There are about 2k of them.

Comment: You mean removing them in bulk, right?

Comment: @alex yes, I want to select and remove all the images below a certain size.